# Remember user and password in my Ionic APP

Tags: ionic2

I have a problem because in my app I need to put a login and password to access and when I access and press physical button return of my smartphone and I leave my app, if I access appear again login page so... my app don't remember user and password. Somebody know how can I solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 5):

Just use nativeStorage from ionic-native:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/nativestorage/

Comment: Keep in mind that storing passwords in plain text is generally not recommended for security reasons. It is advisable to use encryption or other secure methods to store sensitive information like passwords.

Comment: Ideally you never store a password in any way. After the login, you should store a token. Something like a JWT with a set expiration. But to your point, using encrypted storage for this token is certainly better too!

Answer (score 0):

Your app shouldn't remember username and password. Your app should remember an access token (and refresh token) or similar and you could autofill the username and password when your token (or refresh token) expired.

If you use Capacitor you can check the implementation guide for autofilling credentials here:

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/autofill-credentials